# How do I use streamreader to read a text file into a list box in C# windows form application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, streamreader

How do I use StreamReader to read a text file into a list box in C# windows form application? The text file is called Movie Catalog, and the list box is named catalogListBox. What I want to do is make it so that each line from the text file is a different item in the list box. I am using C# windows form application on visual studio. Thank you in advance to those who help!

Answer (score 0):

Will this fit the bill?

```
        string file = @"C:\temp\testfile.txt";
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        string line = "";

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
            }

            listBox1.DataSource = (lines);
        }
```

Comment: Ok, let me try it.

Comment: I have the text file in the debug folder that is in the bin folder for the solution, how do I get it to read from there. Also I tried your code, nothing showed up in the list box unfortunately.

Comment: Nothing is showing up in the list box still. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I'm not sure whats wrong on your end. It's working fine on my end.

Comment: Hold on, I'm going to try and send you my code, can you look at it for me please?

Comment: can we email each other? I really need help with this.

Comment: Ok, you are using a button to read the text file into a list box. What I an trying to do is make the lines from the text box show up as items in a list box as soon as the program starts, not after clicking a button

Comment: You just need to copy that bit of code into a Form Load Event then.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. I didn't select the event handler for the form load event.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.catalogListBox.DataSource = new StreamReader("Movie Catalog").ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] {
                '\n'
            });
```

Comment: I am trying to use StreamReader, nothing else.

Comment: Where do I put this code at? In the catalogListBox method or a new method?